# How to do verify that some code doesn't compile with Bazel?

Tags: bazel

I have several pieces of C++ code (templates, macros, etc) which are intended to not compile when used certain ways. Writing a piece of code by hand which does the things that shouldn't compile and verifying it doesn't compile is easy enough, but that's not automated. It seems like Bazel should be able to compile a piece of code and automatically verify it doesn't compile as part of `bazel test`, and this seems like a fairly common situation with C++ code. Is there a builtin way to do that?

I'm trying to avoid rolling my own Skylark rule that generates a shell script which calls the C++ compiler because handling all the arguments Bazel passes to the C++ toolchain is really hard. Currently, [bazelbuild/bazel#146](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/146) and some other related issues mean all the information isn't even available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a test that creates a scratch workspace and BUILD and C++ files in it, then calls Bazel inside the test, and verifies its exit code and stderr output.

We do similar things all the time with Bazel's own integration tests. See a complete example in commit [e78ad83](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/e78ad83ded6e9c6d639793827e27b6570e6e9f65): the test data-depends on Bazel itself, sets up a mock workspace and BUILD file and runs Bazel as a subprocess, then asserts its stdout (in this case: the result of `bazel info server_pid`). (NB: some of these source files were updated since then, so look at the latest versions.)

Comment: Per [discussion the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/bazel-discuss/tTdB8byeu4Q/discussion), this isn't quite what I was looking for but it's close. I was hoping to avoid duplicating or figuring out how to reuse a custom CROSSTOOL, bazel.rc, and more, but it sounds like that's not possible yet. Once the C++ Skylark API is more complete, this should be easy to solve better, but for now this is a good as it gets. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just create the tests using the code the wrong way as cc_binary targets, and then write a shell script or other tool to call Bazel to build them and check the return code. Not the cleanest way though.

So the shell script would make a bunch of calls to Bazel doing something like this. At least you wouldn't have to figure out the compiler calls Bazel makes, but you lose the nice integrated testing of Bazel.

```
bazel build //tests:test_that_should_fail_at_compile_time
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "Test Passed!"
fi
```